# how to pass a string from 2nd character onwards as parameter in the function for recursion with constraint that data tye is String in function?

Tags: c++, string

```
void someFunction(node * root, string s)
{  
 //some base condition;

    node *tem;
    for(char i= 0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(s[i]=='1'){
            tem=root->right;
            someFunction(root->right,s+1);   
        }
        else{
            tem = root->left;
            decode_huff(tem, s+1)
        }
        tem=root;
    }
}
```

This is showing error .

Comment: *"This is showing error"* - which you completely omitted from your post, for inexplicable reasons. Whenever asking about code that produces compile-time errors, **always** include *both* a [mcve] producing the error *and* the full, verbatim error text *that* code produces as part of your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your function takes a `std::string` by value, so every time you call the function, a new `string` must be created for it.  To create a new `std::string` from a piece of another `std::string`, use the [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method.

Also, `std::string` is not a null-terminated string, you should be looping based on its `size()` instead of its characters:

```cpp
void someFunction(node * root, string s)
{  
    //some base condition;

    node *tem;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if (s[i] == '1'){
            tem = root->right;
            someFunction(root->right, s.substr(i+1));   
        }
        else{
            tem = root->left;
            decode_huff(tem, s.substr(i+1));
        }
        tem = root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass s.substr(i+1) as the second parameter to someFunction.